# Why the variable declaration is showing error in Windows 8 application?

Tags: javascript, .net, html, windows-8, winjs

I am working on windows 8 Winjs application. This is the code where I am declaring variables in javascript. Why the 2nd line is showing error "0x800a138f - JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'getContext' of undefined or null reference." Is the way of declaring canvas.getcontext is wrong? The same code works fine in desktop chrome but it's not working in Simulator.

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas'),
        context = canvas.getContext('2d'),
        controls = document.getElementById('controls'),
        animateButton = document.getElementById('animateButton');
```

Comment: Does an element with an id of `'canvas'` exist at the time that code runs? If not your `canvas` variable will be `null`, hence the error.

Comment: id = "canvas" exists in html document. If I remove this line it executes with blank canvas.

Answer (score 1):

access your dom elements after the page is loaded. that can be done in the page.ready event handler.

```
page.js:
WinJS.UI.Pages.define('/pages/mypage/page.html', 
    {
        ready: function onready(element, options)
        {
            // all dom elements with id will have the respective variables available here.
            // need not create variable for canvas.
            var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
        }
    });
```

page.html:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link href="/pages/mypage/mypage.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="/pages/mypage/mypage.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="mypage fragment">
        <header role="banner">
            <button class="win-backbutton" aria-label="Back" disabled type="button"></button>
            <h1 class="titlearea win-type-ellipsis">
                <span class="pagetitle">My Page</span>
            </h1>
        </header>
        <section aria-label="Main content" role="main">
            <canvas id="canvas">
            </canvas>
        </section>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: And remember that you can add a breakpoint to the line that's giving you trouble (F9), run in debug mode (F5), and then inspect that line in the Quick Watch window (Shift + F9). If you do that and enter `document.getElementById('canvas')` into the Quick Watch evaluation box and hit Enter you'd see `null` meaning it couldn't find the canvas.

Answer (score 0):

There is no element with id canvas loaded. Your `var canvas` is `null` after the assignment. Make sure you are performing all this inside you `app.ready` callback when the `DOM` is ready.

```
app.onready = function (args) {
    var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas'),
        context = canvas.getContext('2d'),
        controls = document.getElementById('controls'),
        animateButton = document.getElementById('animateButton');
}
```